# Pass data as object to mongoDb, use it as query and compare

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document in my mongoDB

[image]

I pass the object from my frontend (user should type something in input filed, for example he types 'test':

```
{'countdown': 'test'}
```

And then I pass it to my backend and want to check if he typed right

```
app.post('/answ', function(req, res) {
  var query = req.body;
  Model.find(query
  , function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      if(result.length!== 0) {
        res.json('ok');
      } else {
        res.json('not found');
      }
    } else {
       res.send(JSON.stringify({
         error : 'Error'
       }))
    }
  })
});
```

So, if key-value pair exist, backend will return **ok**, otherwise **not found**.
It works for such simple object, but if I try to pass something like:

```
{'apilisttask': { 'port': '1', 'host': '2', 'path': '3', 'query': '4' } }
```

In this example user has 4 input fields, I gather all answers and pass it to the backend, but it doesn't give me ok even if the answers are right.

Could you please advice maybe a better approach to compare the data or how to fix the second comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to find in an embedded document, you can not query embedded doc like that.

To query embedded doc, you need to do something like this:

```
Model.find({'apilisttask.port':query.apilisttask.port, 'apilisttask.host':query.apilisttask.host, ...}, function(err, result){
  // ---
});
```

This should do the trick.